# What`s a good greedy 2D-Matrix Sorting Algorithm for such problem?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, multidimensional-array, greedy

My input is a matrix A with vec2 with eg. 6 by 6 fields, means 36 objects.

```
{{{0,0},{1,0},{2,0},{3,0},{4,0},{5,0}},
 {{0,1},{1,1},{2,1},{3,1},{4,1},{5,1}},
 {{0,2},{1,2},{2,2},{3,2},{4,2},{5,2}},
 {{0,3},{1,3},{2,3},{3,3},{4,3},{5,3}},
 {{0,4},{1,4},{2,4},{3,4},{4,4},{5,4}},
 {{0,5},{1,5},{2,5},{3,5},{4,5},{5,5}}}
```

My goal is, to create a smaller matrix B (eg. 3 by 3 fields) with a randomized set of objects out of A, which is sorted in the way, that the distance to the corresponding original position is as small as possible for all vec2 on average.

My selected vec2´s are for example:

```
{{2,1},{4,1},{0,3},{3,0},{5,4},{5,0},{2,4},{2,3},{4,5}}
```

In this example {2,1} would correspond (in Mat A) with:

```
 {2,0},{3,0}
 {2,1},{3,1}
```

{4,1} would correspond with:

```
 {4,0},{5,0}
 {4,1},{5,1}
```

{0,3} would correspond with:

```
 {0,2},{1,2}
 {0,3},{1,3}
```

so their place in new Matrix would be:

```
{{{ - },{2,1},{4,1}},
  {0,3},{ - },{ - }},
  { - },{ - },{ - }}}
```

so far so good

next object is {3,0}, it also corresponds (in Mat A) to

```
 {2,0},{3,0}
 {2,1},{3,1}
```

So optimal place in Matrix would be in first row, second column.

But there is another object ({2,1}). So we have to find an near alternative place.
The field {first row, first column} or the field {second row, second column } would be good.
We chose second:

```
{{{ - },{2,1},{4,1}},
  {0,3},{3,0},{ - }},
  { - },{ - },{ - }}}
```

and so on for all objects.

but I guess after first time filling matrix B, the position will not be good for all the objects, and some must be swapped again and again.

So my Question is which greedy algorithm could help me to get smallest distances for all of the matrixobjects to their origin?

---

I uploaded a picture for better understanding.

[image: Sample]

Red are the superpixels, black subpixels. Distance between blue and green smallest possible distance=>error. The distance between yellow and green produces higher error, because higher taxicab distance.

Comment: "In this example {2,1} would correspond (in Mat A) with..." what are the rules for determining which vectors in Mat A correspond to the randomly chosen vector from Mat A? When you have a conflict, you also seem to arbitrarily choose whichever is closest. You seem to be using a greedy algorithm? Is that what you want?

Comment: And how do you calculate the error? Is it taxicab distance? Are we trying to minimize the total error? RMS of the error?

Comment: The matrices are intended to store pixels from an image. Matrix A is uncompressed, matrix B compressed by factor 2. so a cluster of 4 pixels has a center in the middle with taxicab distance of 0.5 to each pixel of cluster. pixels arround would have higher taxicab distance to the cluster center. Yes I think it must be a greedy algorithm.

Comment: RMS of the error.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is how to pack N random pixels into N cells. Presumably matching a pixel to its "home" cell yields an error of 0. If a pixel has to be placed in a vertically or horizontally adjacent cell, call that an error of 1. What is the error if a pixel is placed in a cell diagonally adjacent to its home cell?

Comment: I uploaded a picture for better understanding. https://imgur.com/NWq3dE0 Red are the superpixels, black subpixels. Distance between blue and green smallest possible distance=>error. The distance between yellow and green produces higher error, because higher taxicab distance

Comment: I do not understand that picture.

Comment: In pic there is a 4*4 Mat  compressed to 2*2 Mat.  Means 16 Pixels now are represented by 4 Pixels. But not with an average as usual while downscaling, represented by 4 random chosen Pixels.